# Obtain reference to a UserControl from a different appdomain (composite UI)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, remoting, appdomain

How might I host a WinForms `Control` (or WPF `Window` for that matter) created in a different AppDomain on a form created in my application?

I'm trying to create a composite UI application that is a featureless shell/host for plugins, where those plugins run entirely in their own app domains, so I want to be able to get UserControl objects from those plugins to be "hosted" in some sort of container control on the host process's main form.

I thought I'd cracked it, but because conversations between appdomains involve MarshallByRefObject proxies, I can't take my first prototype approach of:

```
shellForm.Panel1.Controls.Add(proxyObjectForUserControlInOtherAssembly);
```

I've posted the exception I got from this at the end of the question.

I did have a go at getting the control directly:

```
var ctl = Control.FromHandle(proxyObjectForUserControlInOtherAssembly.Handle);
shellForm.Panel1.Controls.Add(ctl);
```

This gave predictable results. I got the hWnd okay, but `Control.FromHandle()` returned null. Presumably because the handle was created on a different appdomain.

I'd very much appreciate a poke in the right direction if I'm hopelessly off track with this. :)

Many thanks in advance.

---

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Remoting cannot find field 'parent' on type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Object.GetFieldInfo(String typeName, String fieldName)
       at System.Object.FieldGetter(String typeName, String fieldName, Object& val)
       at System.Object.FieldGetter(String typeName, String fieldName, Object& val)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
       at AppDomainTest.Shell.Form1.Display(Control control) in c:\temp\AppDomainTest\AppDomainTest\AppDomainTest.Shell\Form1.cs:line 24
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been helpfully pointed in one possible direction by a colleague: [.NET Add-in Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx)

The key point from that page for my purposes is as follows:

> The assemblies for these segments are
>   not required to be in the same
>   application domain. You can load an
>   add-in into its own new application
>   domain, into an existing application
>   domain, or even into the host's
>   application domain. You can load
>   multiple add-ins into the same
>   application domain, which enables the
>   add-ins to share resources and
>   security contexts.

Comment: Hi Neil. Did you end up using the .Net AddIn framework? From what've read it is possible to host WPF windows created in a different AppDomain (WPF comes with already implemented adapters for that), but not possible for Windows Forms. Did you try to create your own adapters to pass WinForms controls?